# Can you add the close, minimize and maximise buttons to the gnome panel?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-panel

I saw a post on a forum mention an app or applet you could use to add the close, minimize and maximise buttons to the gnome panel (similar to the global menu, but for window controls). However, I can't find any more information online - can't find an app, an applet or anything else. Does anyone know if this actually exists and, if it does, where I could find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, typical. I kept looking and found what I was looking for in the end on [UbuntuGuide](http://ubuntuguide.net/substitute-maximized-window-title-and-buttons-with-gnome-panel-applets).